# Is it possible to modify spaCy by udpipe within the Rasa-NLU?

Tags: rasa-nlu, udpipe

I am several days testing Rasa-NLU, which internally uses spaCy. I had a great disappointment about the Portuguese language. Trying to figure out how to improve the training data, I found an excellent script comparing spaCy with udpipe that can be [checked in this link](https://github.com/jwijffels/udpipe-spacy-comparison) and also in the image below.

[image]

I would like to know if I can continue using Rasa-NLU, but replace the engine spaCy for udpipe?

Comment: You might want to ask this on the [github page](https://github.com/bnosac/udpipe) of the udpipe developer . I know you can use `as_conllu` which converts spacyr output to conllu format, but not if you can use it the other way.

Comment: @phiver I asked the Rasa team, they ruled out the UDPipe for not having vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rasa is open-source it's very easy customizable. In your case you could build your own NLU component as it's described in [this blog post](https://blog.rasa.com/enhancing-rasa-nlu-with-custom-components/).